# how to find strings left and right from named entity with spacy

Tags: python, spacy, named-entity-recognition, nlp

I'm new in Python and NLP (using SpaCy), so I'm hoping someone can help me out. I want to detect the Named Entities in my text and right after I want to get five words left and right from the NEs.

I found already the NEs but I'm stuck finding the "surrounding words"

```
import spacy

nlp=spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

doc = nlp(open(path to my text).read())

for index, token in enumerate(doc.ents): 
    if token.label_ == "PERSON" and token.text == "Frodo" or token.text == "Frodo Beutlin":
        print(token[:index])
        print(token[index])
        print(token[index:])
```

```
Frodo Beutlin
think
```

This is my result, as you can see the strings before my NE are not shown. Also I am confused how to get more than one string (before and after).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your help! I was indeed wrong about the type, now it's working ;)

```
for index, token in enumerate(doc.ents): 
    if token.label_ == "PERSON":
        if token.text == "Frodo Beutlin":
            span = doc.ents[index]
            for i in range(1,6):
                wordsBefore = doc[span.start - i]
            for i in range(1,6):
                wordsAfter = doc[span.start + i]
```

Answer (score -1):

The entities in `doc.ents` are of type `Span`. With the square brackets, you only index the tokens within the span. The entity has fields `start` and `end` which can be used to index tokens in the original document.

```py
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("My name is Frodo Beutlin.")

entity = doc.ents[0]
print(f"Token on the left: '{doc[entity.start - 1]}'")
print(f"Token on the right: '{doc[entity.end]}'")
```

```
Token on the left: 'is'
Token on the right: '.'
```

Comment: `span` is not defined in your snippet.